# Attemping to manipulate data entry for a web page using jsoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am attempting to enter data to a web site. I will post the important snippet of the web site here, but the target web page can be found [here](http://icare.fairfaxcounty.gov/ffxcare/search/commonsearch.aspx?mode=address)

The values are a street address number and a street name represented  by
`inpNumber` and `inpStreet`.

#### HTML:

```html
<td width="48">
  <input type="text" id="inpNumber" name="inpNumber" class="Input" size="5" value="" onkeypress="clearAction(this)" />
</td>

<td width="40">
  <input type="text" id="inpUnit" name="inpUnit" class="Input" size="4" value="" onkeypress="clearAction(this)" />
</td>

<td width="160">
  <input type="text" id="inpStreet" name="inpStreet" class="Input" size="20" value="" onkeypress="clearAction(this)" />
</td>
```

Only `inpStreet` and `inpNumber` are needed for an effective query and I need to enter these values.

#### What I have tried so far:

```
String url = "http://icare.fairfaxcounty.gov/ffxcare/search/commonsearch.aspx?mode=address";    
try {
    Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                .timeout(10 * 10000)
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .data("inpNumber", "4127")
                .data("inpUnit", "")
                .data("inpStreet", "Winter Harbor")
                .data("btSearch", "")
                .data("inpSuffix1", "")
                .followRedirects(true)
                .execute();

    //parse the document from response
    Document document = response.parse();
    System.out.println(" extracting information from site ");
    
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("doc.html");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(document.html());
    bw.close();
} catch (Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have also tried several variations on the above code, including more/less key/pair values (setting and returning "" values found from looking at firebug), looking at all return values and general changes to the `Jsoup.connect(url)` call.

The result I get in `doc.html` file is the original unaltered page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is being sent as a payload and the best way I would use to send the information is by using `requestBody(String)`. The code below is tested working.

#### Imports:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import static java.net.URLEncoder.encode;
```

#### Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "http://icare.fairfaxcounty.gov/ffxcare/search/commonsearch.aspx?mode=address";
    String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0";

    try {

        // GET required information for validation
        // Note that you might want to make a method out of this and call it whenever you need to instead of always
        Elements inputs = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .userAgent(userAgent)
                .get().select("input");

        String eventValidation = encode(inputs.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION").attr("value"), "UTF-8");
        String viewStateGen = encode(inputs.select("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR").attr("value"), "UTF-8");
        String viewState = encode(inputs.select("#__VIEWSTATE").attr("value"), "UTF-8");


        int number = 4127;
        String street = encode("Winter Harbor", "UTF-8");

        // not necessary
        String unit = "";
        String suffix = "";

        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .userAgent(userAgent)
                .requestBody(
                        String.format(
                                "mode=ADDRESS"
                                + "&__VIEWSTATE=%s"
                                + "&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=%s"
                                + "&__EVENTVALIDATION=%s"
                                + "&inpNumber=%d"
                                + "&inpUnit=%s"
                                + "&inpStreet=%s"
                                + "&inpSuffix1=%s", 
                                viewState, viewStateGen, eventValidation,
                                number, unit, street, suffix))
                .post();


        System.out.println("Extracting information from the site...");

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("doc.html");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(document.html());
        bw.close();

        System.out.println("Done.");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //TODO Handle exceptions
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: This would make a useful addition to the Jsoup cookbook as I do not think it is covered.